# How we can convert JObject to array

Tags: json, multidimensional-array

I Have a Newtonsoft JSON jObject variable with multidimensional array . 
Value is listed below. I would like to convert this jObject to  Array so we can manage the array in c# very easily. anybody have done slimier please help me.

```
{
  "DRIVER_CODE": "hk",
  "DRV_NAME": "hk",
  "DRV_ADDR": "hk",
  "DRV_DOB_DT": "07-01-2013",
  "DRV_NATIONALITY": "7",
  "DRV_PHONE1": "kh",
  "DRV_PHONE2": "hk",
  "DRV_MOBILE1": "hk",
  "DRV_MOBILE2": "hk",
  "DRV_LIC_NO": "hk",
  "DRV_LIC_ENDORSE": "hk",
  "DRV_LIC_ISSUE_DT": "08-01-2013",
  "DRV_LIC_EXPIRY_DT": "15-01-2013",
  "DRV_LIC_ISSUEDAT": "hk",
  "DRV_USER_CODE": "hk",
  "DRV_USER_PIN": "hk",
  "DRV_STATUS": 1,
  "DRV_RELIGION": "1",
  "DRV_WEEKLYOFF": "0",
  "DRV_PASSPORT_NUMBER": "hk",
  "DRV_ISSUED_AT": "kh",
  "DRV_ISSUED_DATE": "10-01-2013",
  "DRV_EXPIRY_DATE": "18-01-2013",
  "DRV_VISA_SPONSOR": "kh",
  "DRV_VISA_NUMBER": "hk",
  "DRV_VISA_ISSUEDATE": "17-01-2013",
  "DRV_VISA_EXPIRYDATE": "15-01-2013",
  "DRV_LANG1_CODE": "ARB",
  "DRV_LANG2_CODE": "CHN",
  "DRV_LANG3_CODE": "ENG",
  "NONAVAILABILITY": [
    {},
    {
      "id": 1,
      "fromdate": "15-01-2013",
      "todate": "15-01-2013",
      "reasonVal": "Compassionate Leave",
      "ReasonID": "4"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "fromdate": "30-01-2013",
      "todate": "23-01-2013",
      "reasonVal": "Haj Leave",
      "ReasonID": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "fromdate": "30-01-2013",
      "todate": "23-01-2013",
      "reasonVal": "Haj Leave",
      "ReasonID": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "fromdate": "30-01-2013",
      "todate": "23-01-2013",
      "reasonVal": "Haj Leave",
      "ReasonID": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "fromdate": "30-01-2013",
      "todate": "23-01-2013",
      "reasonVal": "Haj Leave",
      "ReasonID": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to convert NONAVAILABILITY object to array but it is not  sucess. anybody have converted this please submit that will relay helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   JArray nonavailability_array = (JArray)role["NONAVAILABILITY"];

    for (Int32 i = 1; i < nonavailability_array.Count; i++)
     {
       JObject aItem = (JObject)nonavailability_array[i];
       datetime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(aItem["fromdate"].ToString().Replace('"', ' ').Trim());
      }
```